# Dataexporter returns empty rows after filtering

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable, jsf-2.2, data-export

I have a datatable in my xhtml view with filtering enabled. Additionally, there's the Primefaces export (for Excel) function in the context menu. When I use this function without filtering the datatable it works fine, but when I filter first and den export the data I get a file with empty rows.

This is my code:

```
<p:panel header="#{msg['prs.list']}">
    <p:contextMenu for="persons">
        <p:menuitem value="#{msg['com.view']}" icon="#{msg['icon.view']}"
                    action="#{personBean.redirectToEditPerson}"/>
        <p:menuitem value="#{msg['student.new']}" icon="#{msg['icon.new']}"
                    action="#{personBean.redirectToNewStudent}"/>
        <p:menuitem value="#{msg['prs.new']}" icon="#{msg['icon.new']}"
                    url="edit.xhtml"/>
        <p:menuitem value="#{msg['report.export.excel']}" ajax="false" icon="#{msg['icon.export']}">
            <p:dataExporter type="xls" target="persons" fileName="export"  />
        </p:menuitem>
    </p:contextMenu>
    <p:dataTable id="persons" var="person" value="#{personBean.personList}"
                 rowKey="#{person.id}" selection="#{personBean.selectedPerson}" selectionMode="single"
                 emptyMessage="#{msg['com.noEntries']}" paginator="true" rows="15">

        <p:column headerText="Id">
            <h:outputText value="#{person.id}"/>
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="#{msg['prs.name']}" filterBy="name" filterMatchMode="contains">
            <h:outputText value="#{person.name}"/>
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="#{msg['prs.surname']}" filterBy="surname" filterMatchMode="contains">
            <h:outputText value="#{person.surname}"/>
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="#{msg['prs.email']}" filterBy="email" filterMatchMode="contains">
            <h:outputText value="#{person.email}"/>
        </p:column>

    </p:dataTable>
    <f:facet name="footer">
        <p:button value="#{msg['prs.new']}" icon="#{msg['icon.new']}"
                  outcome="edit"/>
    </f:facet>
</p:panel>
```

I'm using Primefaces 4, JSF 2 and Java 7 on Wildfly 8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved. I found a warning in my log regarding the filteredValue property of the datatable.

```
[0m[33m17:26:45,701 WARNING [org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable] (default task-4) DataTable form:persons has filtering enabled but no filteredValue model reference is defined, for backward compatibility falling back to page viewstate method to keep filteredValue. It is highly suggested to use filtering with a filteredValue model reference as viewstate method is deprecated and will be removed in future.
```

I therefore added this property which then solved the problem

```
<p:dataTable id="persons" var="person" value="#{personBean.personList}" 
    rowKey="#{person.id}" selection="#{personBean.selectedPerson}" 
    selectionMode="single" emptyMessage="#{msg['com.noEntries']}" 
    paginator="true" rows="15" filteredValue="#{personBean.filtered}">
```

And added the following property in PersonBean as well

```
private List<PersonEntity> filtered;
public List<PersonEntity> getFiltered() { return filtered; }
public void setFiltered(List<PersonEntity> filtered) { this.filtered = filtered; }
```