# Primefaces export filtred data

Tags: primefaces, filter, data-export

I have a problem with primefaces data export. Export works fine but after I started using filter I got empty file, but I find solutin here: [Dataexporter returns empty rows after filtering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25608691/dataexporter-returns-empty-rows-after-filtering) . But it still doesn't work correctly. Now when I press export I get file with all results not only results after filtering. How can I achieve it? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I find out problem, I had wrong set scope in managed bean. When I changed if from Request to View everything works.